# complicated and interesting Ruby inject method. What does it do?

Tags: ruby, inject

I'm having trouble understanding whats going on with this inject method. Its from a previous version of the octokit gem 1.25.0

```
VALID_OPTIONS_KEYS = [
      :adapter,
      :faraday_config_block,
      :api_version,
      :api_endpoint,
      :web_endpoint,
      :status_api_endpoint,
      :login,
      :password,
      :proxy,
      :oauth_token,
      :client_id,
      :client_secret].freeze
```

and here is the action

```
VALID_OPTIONS_KEYS.inject({}){|o,k| o.merge!(k => send(k)) }
```

can anyone help me out. I'm interested in the various ways this can be explained. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VALID_OPTIONS_KEYS` holds all the symbolic method names. Now the line `VALID_OPTIONS_KEYS.inject({}){|o,k| o.merge!(k => send(k)) }` will create a Hash where `key` will be the name of the symbolic method and value will be the result of the symbolic method.

Very similar to below:

```
VALID_OPTIONS_KEYS = [
      :downcase,
      :upcase].freeze

VALID_OPTIONS_KEYS.inject({}){|o,k| o.merge!(k => "aa".send(k)) }
# => {:downcase=>"aa", :upcase=>"AA"}
```

The documentation [**`Enumerable#inject`**](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) is very clear to understand how `inject` works.

> If you specify a block, then for each element in enum the block is passed an accumulator value (memo) and the element. If you specify a symbol instead, then each element in the collection will be passed to the named method of memo. In either case, the result becomes the new value for memo. At the end of the iteration, the final value of memo is the return value for the method.

So we pass `inject` at the beginning an empty Hash `o`. Then inside the block with each pass the Hash object `o`, using the method [**`Hash#merge`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21),keep updating with new *key/value* pair. Where *key* is the method name from the array `VALID_OPTIONS_KEYS`, and the value is the result of the method call.

Hope it will help you!